# Django import issues not working propely

Tags: python, django

i'm passing this guide: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html

It instruct to do:

> We no longer have to import get_template, Template, Context, or
>   HttpResponse. Instead, we import django.shortcuts.render. The import
>   datetime remains.

However when I'm doing it in my code:

```
from django.http import Http404
import datetime
from  django.shortcuts.render
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})
```

I get these errors:

on import render line:

> Expected:import

on render code line:

> Undefined variable: render

if I change the import to :

```
from  django.shortcuts import render
```

then everything is working.

Why is this happaning?

**EDIT:**

```
 from django.http import Http404
    import datetime
    import django.shortcuts.render
    def current_datetime(request):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})
```

not working either see print screen:

http://i57.tinypic.com/5cyiz7.png

it tells me that the import is unused and still doesn't recognize render

Comment: Either it should be: `import django.shortcuts.render`, or the one which worked in your case.

Comment: as I said import django.shortcuts.render gives errors.... Thats exactly my question. Why one works and the other isn't

Comment: No you  have `from  django.shortcuts.render` in your code not  `import django.shortcuts.render`

Comment: @aayush: As I seen in your code, it's `from django.shortcuts.render`, which definitely won't work.

Comment: you are right. see edit

Comment: If you import the "fully qualified" path `import django.shortcuts.render` you can use it as such with `django.shortcuts.render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case it should be

```
    import django.shortcuts.render as render
```

and use

```
    return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})
```

If you use only **import django.shortcuts.render** instead of **import django.shortcuts.render as render**. Then, **return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})** won't work. Use return **django.shortcuts.render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})** instead.

Comment: import django.shortcuts.render is not working.. plese see my edit

Comment: if you use only import django.shortcuts.render instead of import django.shortcuts.render as render. Then, return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now}) won't work. Use  return django.shortcuts.render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now}) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`from  django.shortcuts.render` 
except this you need to do `import django.shortcuts.render`.

Or `from django.shortcuts import render` as you did last.

In your second edit you did `import django.shortcuts.render` but calling only `render` so `return` like this

`return django.shortcuts.render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})`

Your final code should be:-

```
from django.http import Http404
import datetime
import django.shortcuts.render
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return django.shortcuts.render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})
```

Comment: import django.shortcuts.render not working... see my edit.

Comment: @aayushdagra check my Edit.